# Why unit circle is not diffeomorphic to the real line

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I read from a text book that unit circle ($\mathbb{S}$) is not diffeomorphic to the real line. This result is intuitive since we cannot construct a smooth function from $\mathbb{S}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that it is onto (e.g., $f(\rho)=(\cos(\rho),\sin(\rho))$ defined from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{S}$ is not onto). How can I prove this result?

Incidentally, I am not familiar with advanced topics in topology. Thank you, in advance, for your response!

Comment: Do you know what is a compact space ? A connected space ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet: I am familiar with compact sets and connected sets.

Comment: This gives you two possible ways to show that they can't be diffeomorphic since they can't be homeomorphic.

Comment: For a proof that's specific to differential geometry: every 1-form on $\mathbb{R}$ is exact, but there is a 1-form "$d\theta$" on $S^1$ which is not exact.

Answer (score 4):

The two sets, the unit circle and the real line are not even homeomorphic.

Note that removing a point from the real line makes it disconnected but removing a point form the unit circle keeps it connected.